# Laravel request redirects if there is an error

Tags: laravel

If I remove the "|exists:categories,id" part in the request, it works fine, but if I don't remove it and send a value that is not in the database (there are 10 rows and I send 15), it redirects to the get_categories method. Can someone explain why it does this? And how do I prevent it?

web.php

```
Route::prefix('category')->withoutMiddleware(VerifyCsrfToken::class)
->group(function () {
    Route::get('get', [CategoryController::class, 'get_categories']);
    Route::post('update', [CategoryController::class, 'update_category']);
});
```

CategoryController.php

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    // public function get_categories()
    // {
    //     $categories = Category::all();
    //     return response()->json([
    //         'status' => true,
    //         'message' => 'success.',
    //         'data' => $categories
    //     ]);
    // }

    public function update_category(UpdateCategoryRequest $request)
    {
        dd("not accessing here");
    }
}
```

UpdateCategoryRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateCategoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'required|integer|exists:categories,id',
            'name' => 'nullable|string|max:90',
            'description' => 'nullable|string',
            'title' => 'nullable|string',
            'slug' => 'nullable|string',
            'image_id' => 'nullable|integer|exists:images,id',
        ];
    }

    public function messages(): array
    {
        return [
            'id.required' => 'Category id is required.',
            'id.integer' => 'Category id must be an integer.',
            'id.exists' => 'Category not found.',
            'name.string' => 'Category name must be of text type.',
            'name.max' => 'Category name must be at most 90 characters.',
            'description.string' => 'Description must be in text type.',
            'title.string' => 'Title must be in text type.',
            'slug.string' => 'Slug must be of text type.',
            'image_id.integer' => 'Image id must be an integer.',
            'image_id.exists' => 'Image not found.',
        ];
    }
}
```

[image: postman result]

When I send an id value that does not exist when there is "|exists:categories,id" in the request, I expect it to throw an error like "id not found in categories" ..etc at least not to redirect to another route.

Comment: The first error in the image claims: `Method ... CategoryController::get_categories does not exist`, but this function is commented-out in the controller?

Comment: I don't want it to redirect to this method anyway. If there is any validate error in my request classes, I want it to write directly to the screen, but it redirects. @PaulT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a validation error occurs in a form request, Laravel automatically redirects the user back to their previous location. In the case of an HTTP request, a redirect response will be sent back to the user, along with all the validation errors. This is why you are being redirected to the `get_categories` method.

The `exists:categories,id` rule in your `UpdateCategoryRequest` is checking if the submitted `id` exists in the `categories` table. A validation error is triggered if it doesn't exist, causing the redirect.

If you want to change this behavior and return a JSON response instead of a redirect, you can override the `failedValidation` method in your `UpdateCategoryRequest` class.

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class UpdateCategoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    // ...

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
    }
}
```